# Cleanest way to prematurely exit a jenkins pipeline from inside a withEnv

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkinsfile

In a Jenkins scripted pipeline with the below structure, the `return` command will exit only the `withEnv`.

```
node{
    withEnv([...]){
        stage('1'){
        ...
        }

        stage('2'){
        .....
        }

        if( env.BRANCH_NAME != 'master' ) {
            currentBuild.result = 'SUCCESS'
            return
        }

        stage('3'){
        ...
        }       
    }

    stage('4'){
        withEnv([...]){
            ...
        }
    }

    stage('5'){
        ...
    }

    stage('6'){
    ...
    }
}
```

How can I stop the entire pipeline after stage2 with SUCCESS?

Answer (score 2):

Just the way you can exit any stage prematurely by using `return` keyword, you can use the `return` keyword (outside of the stage) to exit the entire pipeline prematurely. You can re-use the `currentBuild.result` value outside of `Stage 4`. See below.

```
node{
    withEnv([...]){
        stage('1'){
        ...
        }

        stage('2'){
        .....
        }

        if( env.BRANCH_NAME != 'master' ) {
            currentBuild.result = 'SUCCESS'
            return
        }

        stage('3'){
        ...
        }       
    }

    stage('4'){
        withEnv([...]){
            ...
        }
    }

    if(currentBuild.result == 'SUCCESS') {
        return //this will exit the pipeline
    }

    stage('5'){
        ...
    }

    stage('6'){
    ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for **error()** function, this question has been answered somehow in: [This question: Abort current build from pipeline in Jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42667600/abort-current-build-from-pipeline-in-jenkins)

Comment: Does error() accept SUCCESS build status?